# Heroku doesn't find distribution in requirements.txt

Tags: python, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my first Python Telegram bot with Heroku, but when I do so two errors occur:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pornhub-api==0.2.0
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pornhub-api==0.2.0
```

Isn the `pornhub-api` module not supported or what? I'm very new to Python so sorry if I'm asking something stupid, but I couldn't find anything that could help me.

The `requirements.txt` file looks like this:

```
telepot==12.7
pornhub-api==0.2.0
```

Thank you!

All the process in which the errors appear:

```
Python app detected
Requirements file has been changed, clearing cached dependencies
Installing python-3.6.10
Installing pip
Installing SQLite3
Installing requirements with pip
   Collecting telepot==12.7
     Downloading telepot-12.7.tar.gz (73 kB)
   ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pornhub- 
 api==0.2.0 (from -r 
/tmp/build_"here the is written the build number"/requirements.txt (line 2)) (from 
versions: none)
   ERROR: No matching distribution found for pornhub-api==0.2.0 (from -r 
/tmp/build_"here the is written the build number"/requirements.txt (line 2))
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
!     Push failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using Python 3.6, while that library says it requires version 3.7 or greater:

```
Installing python-3.6.10
```

You should be able to [request a newer runtime](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes) by adding a file called `runtime.txt` in the root of your repository containing your desired version, committing, and deploying again.

Currently, [Heroku supports](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#supported-runtimes) Python versions

- 3.8.3
- 3.7.7
- 3.6.10
- 2.7.18

If you want to use Python 3.8.3 (why not use the newest if you can?) your `runtime.txt` should contain exactly this:

```
python-3.8.3
```